# casperjs using waituntilvisible for form

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I use Casperjs for task automation and have to fill a form with PickUp Date, DropOff Date and PickUp Location.

Filling PickUp Date and DropOff Date works just fine. (i can check this with screenshot).

When you start filling the fied PickUp Location , a list of choices is build based on what you typed.
This list is displayed inside:

```
 <ul class="ct-autocomplete ct-ui-base" id="ui-id-1" ....></ul>
```

So i tried to use: this.waitUntilVisible('u#ui-id-1', function() 
But I get the following error:

```
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
FAIL "u#ui-id-1" never appeared in 10000ms
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: "u#ui-id-1" never appeared in 10000ms
#    stack: not provided
```

Thanks for your help
Lorenzow

```
casper.options.waitTimeout = 10000;

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

casper.start(url, function() {
   console.log("page loaded");
});

casper.then(function() {
  this.waitForResource(this.getCurrentUrl(),function() {

    //Filling Pick Up Date    
   this.click('input#ct_s1_pickup_date');
   this.fill('form#ct_s1_frm_search', {
    'ct_pickup_date':   '05/04/2015'
   },false);

   //Filling Drop Off Date
   this.click('input#ct_s1_dropoff_date');
   this.fill('form#ct_s1_frm_search', {
    'ct_dropoff_date':   '15/04/2015'
   },false);

   this.capture('screenshot step1.png');

  },function() {
  },5000);
});

casper.then(function() {

    //Filling Pick Up Location
   this.click('input#ct_s1_pickup_loc');
   this.fill('form#ct_s1_frm_search', { 
        'ct_pickup_loc':    'Barcelone'
    },false);

   this.echo(this.getHTML('ul#ui-id-1', true));

   this.waitUntilVisible('u#ui-id-1', function() {
    this.capture('screenshot step3.png');
    });
});

casper.evaluate(function(){
 });

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: You mean `waitUntilVisible('ul#ui-id-1',` instead of `waitUntilVisible('u#ui-id-1',`, right?

Comment: Yes and Tim's solution has worked:
casper.then(function() {
    this.sendKeys('input#ct_s1_pickup_loc','Barcelone',{reset: true,keepFocus: true});
});

Comment: Who is Tim? Why does this code answer your question? You can either answer your own question and accept it after some time or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

"fill" looks not to trigger anything but "sendkeys" does.

So I replaced:

```
this.fill('form#ct_s1_frm_search', { 
        'ct_pickup_loc':    'Barcelone'
    },false);
```

by:

```
casper.then(function() { this.sendKeys('input#ct_s1_pickup_loc','Barcelone',{reset: true,keepFocus: true}); });
```

then a choices list was build based on 'Barcelone' request.